# How to make button change colour in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

How do I make a button change colour in python tkinter 3?
I saw one using the self code but I don't like to use that. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

button = ttk.Button(root, text = "Click Me")
button.pack()
button.config(command = colour_change)

def colour_change():
    button.config(background= "green")
```

Comment: There is an error. It comes up: name ‘colour_change’ is not defined

Comment: Move the function above the button creation code. The function is not defined at the point you try to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by "I saw one using the self code ..." but essentially, you can choose to set background colour of a button:

1. At the time of creation by passing a parameter to constructor

   ```
   btn = Button(root, bg='red') # and other parameters if you like
   ```
2. Whenever you want once the object is created until it's reference is valid by

   ```
   btn.config(bg='green')
   ```

   Now, when exactly you call this method is entirely up to you. It is just that the code snippet that you have shown is doing so at the click of that button itself.

Comment: Are you saying I have to give the button a colour before I can change it due to it being clicked? Also what I meant by the self is how many people when they are these questions provide code with self.button for example rather than just button, or they might define a function and pass through the parameter self

Comment: You need not set any colour it at the time of instantiation. Just call config(bg='green') on the button object when you want the button colour to change.